# Application Level pcap dump

Tags: pcap

Is it possible to dump contents of tcp recv/send to a pcap file and then have wireshark analyse this. I want to do this because I want to log an applications conversations in order to debug issues but I don't want to have to write my own parsers (wireshark already supports it) and don't necessarily trust the application to parse frames correctly.

Comment: Can you not just make your application log all communications?

Answer (score 2):

> What follows is based on work that I've done exclusively on Windows. 
>   I can't speak to how well any of this might apply to other systems. 
>   FWIW, I would suggest editing your question (or at least tagging it)
>   to be more clear about what OS you're targeting.

If you are talking about writing what's received directly from a TCP client to a pcap file, the answer is no.  The [pcap file format](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat) requires at least some networking headers, e.g., the IP and TCP headers, in order for the file to be valid.

There are four approaches I see.

1. You could fake these headers for each read from the socket.  This wouldn't necessarily require a lot of work, but it would require some knowledge of the relationships between the network header, the transport header, and the payload (i.e., your data) in order for everything to work right.  If you're only interested in analysis of the payload in Wireshark, this might be a valid approach.  However, if the analysis you're wanting to do in Wireshark is network analysis (i.e., analysis that includes the network headers), then you'll want to avoid this option and figure out how to capture the network headers directly.
2. You could use a [raw socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to capture network traffic at the network layer.  This will give you the IP packet - IP header, TCP header, and payload.  You could dump this to a pcap file using [LINKTYPE_RAW](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) as the link-layer header type, and Wireshark will read the file fine.  I've used this approach before.
3. The third approach would be to use [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) to collect your data.  This is the same software that Wireshark uses behind the scenes to collect the data, and it's the approach I'm using now.  If you have Wireshark installed, the WinPcap is already installed, too.  WinPcap has a simple API with numerous examples for opening an interface, collecting the data, and dumping it to a pcap or [pcap-ng](http://www.winpcap.org/ntar/draft/PCAP-DumpFileFormat.html) file.
4. The fourth option is the simplest...just use Wireshark to collect the data simultaneously with your application.

HTH.